# Extract three values from JSON output

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get three specific values from within a JSON return. I can only figure out how to get ALL the information rather than specific pieces. Here's the JSON output (note - the date 2021-08-13:2 is going to change every week but I need that value also the 710.0 will likely change, too):

```
{
 "callExpDateMap": {
  "2021-08-13:2": {
   "710.0": [
    {
     "ask": 8.5,
     "askSize": 23,
     "bid": 8.2,
     "bidAskSize": "3X23",
     "bidSize": 3,
     "closePrice": 8.28,
     "daysToExpiration": 2,
     "deliverableNote": "",
     "delta": 0.506,
     "description": "TSLA Aug 13 2021 710 Call (Weekly)",
     "exchangeName": "OPR",
     "expirationDate": 1628884800000,
     "expirationType": "S",
     "gamma": 0.019,
     "highPrice": 0.0,
     "inTheMoney": false,
     "isIndexOption": null,
     "last": 8.25,
     "lastSize": 0,
     "lastTradingDay": 1628899200000,
     "lowPrice": 0.0,
     "mark": 8.35,
     "markChange": 0.07,
     "markPercentChange": 0.88,
     "mini": false,
     "multiplier": 100.0,
     "netChange": -0.03,
     "nonStandard": false,
     "openInterest": 6224,
     "openPrice": 0.0,
     "optionDeliverablesList": null,
     "percentChange": -0.33,
     "putCall": "CALL",
     "quoteTimeInLong": 1628625599948,
     "rho": 0.035,
     "settlementType": " ",
     "strikePrice": 710.0,
     "symbol": "TSLA_081321C710",
     "theoreticalOptionValue": 8.277,
     "theoreticalVolatility": 29.0,
     "theta": -1.127,
     "timeValue": 8.25,
     "totalVolume": 0,
     "tradeDate": null,
     "tradeTimeInLong": 1628625596495,
     "vega": 0.284,
     "volatility": 29.119
    }
   ]
  }
```

What I need is the date (in this case 2021-08-13:2 and also the "ask" and "bid".

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
for response_line in response.iter_lines():
        if response_line:
            json_response = json.loads(response_line)
            #print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=1, sort_keys=True))
            contract_info = json_response['callExpDateMap']
            print(contract_info)
```

I tried things like contract_info = json_response['callExpDateMap'][0] thinking it's list position 0 that would return the date but alas I'm stuck.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: json_response['callExpDateMap']['2021-08-13:2']['710.0'][0]['ask']

Comment: The date is a key in this dictionary. So you can access it by calling `.keys()` on the second outermost level.

Comment: Thanks Darkknight - I didn't make it clear sorry - the date is not always the same date so I would need the first item in the list being the date. Sorry I didn't make that clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fragment based on your variable names that will find all of the 'ask' values:-

```
r = json_response['callExpDateMap']
for k in r.keys():
    for m in r[k].keys():
        for p in r[k][m]:
            print(p['ask'])
```

Comment: Just wanted to ask - how can I get just the very first result in the ask? For example, this code will return all the asks - which is great. What I want is to select the first ask result. I am thinking along the lines of firstAsk = ask[0] but that's not going to do it. I did type(ask) and it tells me it's a float.

Comment: Simplest way is to wrap the code into a function and instead of print() just return p['ask']

Comment: Ignore my last comment - I'm working through the code figuring it out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is it enough?

```
date = list(a['callExpDateMap'].keys())[0]
subdict = list(a['callExpDateMap'][date].values())[0][0]
ask = subdict['ask']
bid = subdict['bid']
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't read the json line-by-line. Instead, parse the entire json to a dictionary and then keep what you want:

```
d = json.loads(json_response)
date = next(iter(d["callExpDateMap"]))
price = next(iter(d["callExpDateMap"][date]))
bid = d["callExpDateMap"][date][price][0]["bid"]
ask = d["callExpDateMap"][date][price][0]["ask"]

>>> bid, ask
(8.2, 8.5)
```